# How to Re-start Bluemix Secured Gateway Docker Client

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

I created the Bluemix Secured Gateway Docker Client in my local environment and everything was working fine.  But after I rebooted my workstation, the Docker Client does not work anymore. I ran the Docker start command, but nothing happened. What should I do to get it working again?

Thanks.

Comment: Absolutely nothing happened?

Comment: Did you invoke it including all the options? Any log/diag output?

Answer (score 0):

Please run the "docker run ..." command from the Secure Gateway UI exactly as it's shown in the Secure Gateway UI. We do not support any of the "docker start/stop/restart" commands.